# Android InApp Purchase Example

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am facing the issue in building **InApp Purchase** Example App give in SDK.

It's showing error in **IMarketBillingService.aidl** because its showing like disabled file.

and the other java files importing this file shows error that

**import com.android.vending.billing.IMarketBillingService cannot be resolved**

Can any one solve this problem or give soemalternate solution for this InApp Billing i need good example for this.

Comment: If you want an alternative Tutorial to the google one, check out this post: http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/simple-inapp-billing-payment-t52060.html

Comment: Did you try to just clean the project?

Comment: @egor ya i tried many times by cleaning and rebuilding the project but no use.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem when trying to integrate the components from the example into my software. The source of the issue for me was that the code I was modifying was an Android library resource to the main project, and somehow the sources in the build path had gotten mixed up.

The solution for me was to (in Eclipse) right-click the project, Build Path, and Configure Build Path. Choose the sources tab at the top, and verify there aren't duplicate sources there, perhaps under different names. If there are, you're going to have to do some fiddling and figure out which ones belong.

I'm not sure how it gets into this situation; it was a long day...

Sorry for the ambiguous answer but I hope it helps anyone in this pickle.

Comment: I really have to thank you for this. I'd upvote you a million times if I could. I spent a considerable amount of time struggling with this annoying problem...

Answer (score 1):

With IDE android studio:

- Step1: right-click app folder and choose new/folder/AIDL Folder
- Step2: right-click aidl folder and choose new/package, make name is    com.android.vending.billing
- Step3: Copy IInAppBillingService.aidl to package com.android.vending.billing
- Step3: Clean and Rebuild

==> It will work!.